# To give the folks a boot

Tags: meaning-in-context, expressions

On page 234 of Peter Benchley’s Jaws, there is an expression whose meaning I can’t get:

> “Watch this. This always gives the folks a boot”

Would you please help me to understand it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

*Boot* here is a US colloquialism meaning “a sudden intense feeling of pleasure or amusement”.  It is a variant of *kick* in the same sense:

> I get a kick out of you.
>   I get no kick from champagne.
>   You could tell the guy got a boot out of his work, giggled as he hammered at the keyboard.
>   Curtiss and I got a boot out of just watching Ken and Snuffy smoke 'em.

It's the suddenness and strength of the sensation you feel which motivates the use of *boot* and *kick*: it affects you as strongly as a powerful blow, but in a positive way.

Comment: If I knew the source was UK rather than US, I'd be inclined to suspect a mistranscription of ***boost***.